# Ajax query, php file is getting read but can't enter success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

so I have the following code that is calling a CheckEmail2.php.  I know what I want to do in CheckEmail2.php but because my Ajax success is not working, I have minded the scope to just return a Json.  below is my java script. When I launch my console, I see my string coming through that I am echoing in my CheckEmail2.php.  so I know my php file is getting read but why won't my success function hit if my string is getting read?  I can't get my success function to get called. It always goes to error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(){
  var email = document.forms["signupform"]["email"].value;
  var result = false;
  if (email != ""){
    $.ajax({           
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/CheckEmail2.php",  
      data: { "User_Email": email },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
        if(resp == "Not Found"){
          result = true;
        }
        else
        {
        result = false;
        }
      },
      error: function(data, status){
        console.log(data, status);
      }
    }); //end Ajax
  }
  return result;
}
</script>
```

here is my PHP

```
<?php

    header("Content-type:application/json");
    echo json_encode("Not Found");

?>
```

why is error always getting called?

Comment: here is my php file.              <?php
header("Content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode("Not Found");
?>

Comment: `echo json_encode(['reply'=> "Not Found"]);` then you will have VALID JSON being sent back

Comment: that did it.  I am now hitting the success function.  Next and hopefully last question.  is my if statement right in the success.  it keeps going to the else statement.  if I am echoing "Not Found", rest should equal "Not Found" correct??

Comment: @BPayne You have to update your `if` condition based on your latest change in response like `if(resp.reply == "Not Found"){`

Comment: so the success is working now but my return result is always going to false.  It is like the validate is returning before my Ajax even completes.  Would this be so?  do I need to do something to my validate to ensure the return value is what is in my success function?  when I look in my console, the validate return is posting before my console dump from the success?